# How to test that Actor Foo sends messages to newly created child actors Bar?

Tags: java, akka

I have an actor `FooActor` that gets passed the `Props` to instantiate several `BarActor`s and send `BarMessage`s to it. The code works, but I am having a hard time writing tests for it. The added restriction is that I can only use Java code in this app, no Scala code.

After several attempts, this seems to be my best effort so far:

```
@Test
public void testJavaTestKit() {

    new JavaTestKit(system) {{
        JavaTestKit probe = new JavaTestKit(system);

        // pretending that the probe is the receiving Bar, by returning it in the Props
        Props barActorProps = Props.create(BarActor.class, new Creator() {
            @Override
            public Object create() {
                return probe.getRef();
            }
        });
        Props props = Props.create(FooActor.class, barActorProps);
        ActorRef subject = system.actorOf(props);

        Object msg = // basically irrelevant, will trigger Bar instantiation and message sending

        subject.tell(msg, probe.getRef());

        expectMsgClass(Bar.BarMessage.class);
        expectNoMsg();
    }};
}
```

It all seems to make sense to me, but even though I can see messages being sent to newly created `Bar` instances, the first assertion fails. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

The thing that makes this different from the Akka documentation example, is that I don't want to pass an existing actor that receives the message. Instead, I want to pass the `Props` that is used to create instances of child actors instead. In the test, I want my `probe` to receive messages to those newly created actors. This is why I added the `Props.create` construct that should return the same probe actor all the time. Just now I saw this comment in the `Creator.create` API:

> This method must return a different instance upon every call.

So this will obviously not work, as that it precisely what I want. So my general question remains: how can I test for messages being sent to newly created child actors?

Comment: Is the probe JavaTestKit ActorRef where you are expecting a message to be sent? If so you would need to call probe.expectMsgClass, at present you are asserting against the anonymous JavaTestKit in your test method. Unless your test "subject" is replying with a Bar.BarMessage.class then that assertion will always fail

Comment: The solution may be as simple as changing the assertion to `probe.expectMsgClass(Bar.BarMessage.class);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That looked really promising, and it may have brought me closer to the solution, though it does not work yet at this moment.

Comment: No probs. Providing the code for `FooActor.class` may help you get the solution you need. When I was initially getting my head around testings Akka Actors using Java I followed the patterns described here [github-link](https://gist.github.com/jconwell?direction=asc&sort=created) and specifically in your case the ForwarderActor sounds like what you are after.

Comment: @JeroenKransen is there any chance to see your FooActor impl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to "cheat" on how the child actors are initialized (by passing `probeRef`) to have flexibility in testing them, but the problem is that the even `Creator` is generic, used in standard context `getContext().actorOf()`, cannot return `ActorRef` as a result of the `create` method. The contract needs always be as follow `Creator<T extends Actor>`.

Please have a look at [ActorCreationTest](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/cb05725c1ec8a09e9bfd57dd093911dd41c7b288/akka-actor-tests/src/test/java/akka/actor/ActorCreationTest.java)

I might be wrong because, I don't know how your `FooActor` is implemented but if you will use stadard pattern `getContext().actorOf()` default Akka `akka.actor.CreatorConsumer` will not accept your `Consumer`.

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: akka.actor.RepointableActorRef cannot be cast to akka.actor.Actor
    at akka.actor.CreatorConsumer.produce(Props.scala:335)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:252)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:552)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
    ... 9 more
```

Instead of returning `ActorRef` to probe you may try return anonymous forwarder `Actor` ?

```
import akka.actor.*;
import akka.japi.Creator;
import akka.testkit.JavaTestKit;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ActorTest {

    @Test
    public void testJavaTestKit() {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("Acceptor");

        new JavaTestKit(system) {{
            JavaTestKit probe = new JavaTestKit(system);

            Creator creator = () -> new UntypedActor() {
              @Override
              public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
                  probe.getRef().tell(message, sender());
              }
            };


            ActorRef subject = system.actorOf(Props.create(FooActor.class, creator));

            subject.tell(new Bar().new BarMessage(), probe.getRef());
            probe.expectMsgClass(Bar.BarMessage.class);


        }};
    }

}


class BarActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

    }
}

class FooActor extends UntypedActor {

    ActorRef barRef;

    public static Props props(final Creator creator) {
        return Props.create(FooActor.class, () -> new FooActor(creator));
    }
    public FooActor(Creator creator) {
        barRef = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(creator),"bar");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        barRef.tell(message,sender());
    }
}

class Bar {
    class BarMessage {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work for your case.

```
class ActorSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    private ActorSystem system
    @Shared
    private ActorRef actorRef
   def setupSpec() {
        system = ActorSystem.create("test-system",ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
    }
   def "Verify message received"() {
     given:
            JavaTestKit probe = new JavaTestKit(system)
            final Props props = Props.create(BarActor.class)
            actorRef = system.actorOf(props)
        when:
            actorRef.tell(new BarMessage(), probe.getRef())
        then:
            probe.expectMsgClass(Bar.BarMessage.class);
    }
 def cleanupSpec() {
        JavaTestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
        system = null
    }
```